# Need help understanding pagination parameters

Tags: pagination

I've been trying to find an explanation of the following code which I'm using to add pagination to a custom category template.

```
$catpage = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
            $catnum = 3;
            $offset = ($catnum * $catpage) - 3;
```

In particular, I would like to know what exactly the query variable "paged" refers to and also the meaning of "offset".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code line:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

is using  the [*ternary operator*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) `?:`

It's a shorthand notation for

```
if( get_query_var( 'paged' ) )
    $paged = get_query_var('paged' );
else
    $paged = 1;
```

This can in fact be simplified further, by using the the second input parameter for the default value, namely:

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );
```

See the `get_query_var()` function definition [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/).

What are query variables?

Let me quote the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars):

> Query vars define a query for WordPress posts.
>
> When ugly permalinks are enabled, query variables can be seen in the
>   URL. For example, in the URL http://example.com/?p=1 the p query var
>   is set to 1, which will display the single post with an ID of 1.
>
> When pretty permalinks are enabled, URLs don't include query
>   variables. Instead, WordPress transforms the URL into query vars via
>   the Rewrite API, which are used to populate the query.

I see you've added more code to the question:

```
$catpage = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$catnum = 3;
$offset = ($catnum * $catpage) - 3;
```

Let's check out the category archive for a category called `blue`:

When the `paged` query variable isn't defined, on the first page

```
http://example.tld/category/blue/
```

then we set it as 1 and then:

```
offset = 3 * 1 - 3 = 0
```

When the `paged` query variable is 2 (on the second page)

```
http://example.tld/category/blue/page/2/
```

then:

```
offset = 3 * 2 - 3 = 6 - 3 = 3
```

When the `paged` query variable is 3 on the third page

```
http://example.tld/category/blue/page/3/
```

then:

```
offset = 3 * 3 - 3 = 9 - 3 = 6
```

etc

Comment: That's not exactly plain English but I appreciate the answer. What exactly is meant by "paged"?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. That definitely helps. What is the "offset" variable actually used for? It's in relation to a get_categories array.

Comment: That depends on your code ;-) It can be used for pagination. If you mean the `WP_Query` then it supports the `offset` argument and it's used to set the `LIMIT` part of the generated SQL query, together with the `posts_per_page` argument. It also supports the `paged` argument, that can be used as well. The `offset` argument overrides the `paged` argument. Both can be overridden by the `nopaging` argument. @jrcollins

Comment: aha, I see you've edit your comment with `get_categories()`. It also supports the `offset` argument to handle pagination, together with the `number` argument,  It's used to set the LIMIT part of the generated term query SQL. @jrcollins

Comment: Ok, thanks. This question is in relation to a problem I'm having adding pagination to a custom category template. I was going to ask another question but maybe I should just edit this one?

Comment: you're welcome. It might be better to ask a new question, to avoid confusion with the current answers to your current question @jrcollins

Comment: Yes, I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

It will return the current page number. If the `paged` variable is not set, it will return `1`. `1` stands for page number 1 in pagination.